# automatically scroll more for full view of div

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

I'm looking for a way to smoothly assist the user of my website with scrolling. I have a long page with div's with the full size of the viewport, so i want when your scrolling down and you stop but you scrolled like 10px or so to far down or up the page automatically scrolls to the right point so the div is totally viewable.

Comment: well, if you could let us know what have you tried so far it would be really helpful. Also, if you could some code snippet or may be code pen or jsfiddle ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this maybe what you are looking for http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#firstPage

Comment: yes that is exactly what i was looking for, just didn't really know how to put it in words

Comment: :) glad i could help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle to show it all [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wsups7p5/6/). For the landing in the right place I use...

```
.className {
    margin-top: -80px;
    padding-top: 80px;
}
```

That gets you landing in the right place. This script from [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/) works great with jquery

Comment: That's not exactly what i'm looking for, close tho. In that example the click on the button is the trigger to scroll down, I want this to be the trigger: jQuery(window).scrollTop() > 400